# Why are there no perfect black bodies?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Is my understanding correct, that all objects emit a perfect black body spectrum only dependent on its temperature, but we cant measure this perfect spectrum because all objects will reflect some of the radiation distorting the reading for the wavelength of radiation reflected.

Since no object is a perfect absorber, no object will exhibit a perfect black body spectrum but it is there underlying and readings you take.

Please point out any errors in my understanding because I am sure I have made many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct, that all objects emit a perfect black body spectrum only dependent on its temperature,

This is the theoretical black body curve. This is modified by the type of material the body consists of, because the underlying level is quantum mechanical and photons have to be absorbed and radiated from specific energy levels, depending on the type of material.

> but we cant measure this perfect spectrum because all objects will reflect some of the radiation distorting the reading for the wavelength of radiation reflected.

It is not just reflection, it is also  quantum mechanical transitions for bodies consisting of different atomic and molecular structures.

The energy radiated from a black body is given by the [Stefan-Boltzman](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/absrad.html) law, for grey bodies, i.e. not ideal black bodies, an emission coefficient is used [dependent on the materials](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/emissivity-coefficients-d_447.html), in order to fit observed emissions.

The best [experimental fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) to the black body formula is the cosmic microwave backround radiation:

[image]

> Graph of cosmic microwave background spectrum measured by the FIRAS instrument on the COBE, the most precisely measured black body spectrum in nature. The error bars are too small to be seen even in an enlarged image, and it is impossible to distinguish the observed data from the theoretical curve.

The [solar spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance) as an  example is approximately a black body curve,(the yellow histogram) because the sun is an active, continuously generating power by fusion , with a lot of plasma surrounding it, which also distorts from the black body curve.

[image]

Comment: which has a greater effect,  reflection or the molecular structure?

Comment: the molecular structure (or fluid mass sructure in the case of the sun). reflection is important in reaching thermodynamic equilibrium, balance between absorption and reflection.